# How to make edge colours a gradient in ggnet2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a plot using the `ggnet2` package in `R`. I have created a network (`net.bg`)

```r
library(igraph)
library(GGally)
library(network)

    direction <- c(2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,3,2,4,2,5,2,4,3,5,3,5,4)
    gr <- matrix(direction, nrow = 2)
    x1 <- 10.59
    x2 <- 15.74
    x3 <- 0
    x4 <- 100
    x5 <- 28.63

    RImp <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
    nam <- names(RImp)
    RImp <- as.numeric(RImp)
    Rint <- c(2.96, 1.34, 1.27, 1.1, 2.22, 1.24, 3.11,
              2.52, 0.96, 1.08)

    net.bg <- make_graph(gr, 5)
```

and I am using `ggnet2` to plot it like so:

```r
library(GGally)
library(igraph)

    p   <- ggnet2(net.bg, 
                  mode = "circle", 
                  size = RImp,
                  color = RImp,
                  node.color = "grey50",
                  label = nam,
                  edge.size = Rint, 
                  edge.label = Rint,
                  edge.color = "grey") 
     p
```

Where, `RImp` is is a set of values that determines the node size, `Rint` determines the edge size, and `nam` is just the name of the nodes.

This produces a plot like the one below:

[image: Network style plot]

However, what I am trying to achieve is to make the edge colour a gradient from low to high values. I was trying something like this:

```r
    colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))
    p   <- ggnet2(net.bg, 
                  mode = "circle", 
                  size = RImp,
                  color = RImp,
                  node.color = "grey50",
                  label = nam,
                  edge.size = Rint, 
                  edge.label = Rint,
                  edge.color = colfunc(length(Rint))) 
     p
```

This colours the edges in the gradient... however, it is not colouring them from low to high values... It is colouring them in the path direction.

Any suggestions as to how I would colours the edges in a gradient from low to high values?

Comment: could you perhaps provide some example data in the structure of your network, please?

Comment: I didn't originally add the data because all the information is included in the diagram and is somewhat arbitrary. But I've edited the question to include the data anyway.

Comment: You're right... I forgot to add the libraries... apologies, I am using ```GGally``` and ```igraph```.... also, yes, asdf should be net.bg, I only spotted that after I posted... but ive changed that in the question

Comment: it's still missing some things. how do you define `df`? of which you're taking the names from?... `Error in ggnet2(net.bg, mode = "circle", size = RImp, color = RImp, node.color = "grey50",  : 
  could not coerce net to a network object`

Comment: Sorry, it's late here and I keep making mistakes. I changed ```df``` to ```RImp``` for the names. But apart from that, the code seems to run for me!?

Comment: sorry, but `RImp` doesn't have any names (yet ;-) I can create the `net.bg` object, but the `ggnet2()` call gives the above error. I suggest you clean your workspace and run only the code that's online here now.

Comment: ```nam``` was in the wrong order. I've edited the question again to fix that. I have cleared my workspace and ran the code as above and it works for me. I'm not sure why you are getting the error. The only thing I can think of is maybe ```GGally``` requires the ```network``` package or something!? But, I've added the libraries to the question as well.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question again. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206326/discussion-between-tobio-and-electrino).